# Vi editor behaving randomly while editing

Tags: aix, vi

When I open a PuTTY session in full screen I can't scroll down and up properly with the down arrow key. It seem to move down the screen and gets stuck somewhere in the middle.

When I open PuTTY in small window it works fine for scrolling down or up. But still when I use l key or right arrow key to move right it seems to delete characters and move with tabs.

Comment: sounds like an encoding problem to me. what's your local encoding, what does putty use for an encoding and what is the actual encoding on the remote machine?

Comment: It only problem for AIX server it wokrs fine on other servers.I dont know where to check encoding for the remote machine.

Answer (score 3):

It's to do with your terminal on the aix server. You can check your terminal with

```
env|grep -i term
```

`man resize` should help too. Does just typing `resize` reflect your correct putty size?